# Nemo file manager - change focus from the sidebar to the main view (automatically)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, nemo, focus

**Edit:** [GitHub issue report](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/1230)

I find it hard to change focus (either by keyboard, or automatically) from the sidebar to the contents view in Nemo 2.8.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. Nautilus does not have this problem.

I want to be able to navigate through folders quickly, by typing in starting characters of folders, using arrows and pressing enter/backspace, without having to use a mouse, or possibly any shortcut to switch the problematic focus on the sidebar.

[image]

#### How I can switch:

- using a mouse
- by switching between icon/list/compact views with a shortcut - <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd> (ridiculous)
- by opening the bookmarked folder in a new window - <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> (even more so)
- by opening the bookmarked folder in a new tab - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>, switching to the previous tab and back with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (...)

#### How I want to switch:

- at the first click/<kbd>return</kbd> key press on the sidebar.
- also with a shortcut (like <kbd>tab</kbd>), back and forth

What can be done about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Hit <kbd>F3</kbd> twice.

---

You can toggle the focus between the sidebar and the current tab with <kbd>F6</kbd>. Works <strike>flawlessly</strike> for me in Nemo 5.2.4.

**Edit:** After trying this solution a bit more, I now sometimes encountered situations where <kbd>F6</kbd> didn't work. I then had to click once into the current window, afterwards it worked again. Strange and unpleasant behaviour.

**Edit 2**: One way to reproduce the problem is to open the search bar and close it again (<kbd>2x Ctrl-F</kbd>). <kbd>F6</kbd> doesn't work then. However, hitting <kbd>F3</kbd> twice works for me.

Comment: `F6` works for Ubuntu 22 Files and is not documented in the *shorcuts* pane. However, when typing `return` it does not act as the focus is on the sidebar...